# Read persisted data when validating a field in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django model Item that has a 'device_date' DateTimeField

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...
    device_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I'm using DRF, so I have a Serializer for this model:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

When I update an item (PUT method) I'd like to check if the 'device_date' sent by the client is greater that the one that it's already in the database. If the received 'device_date' is not greater that the existing one, the server should reply a HTTP 400 error and do not persist the object. If I define a validate method in this serializer

```
def validate_device_date(self, value):
```

I have available the value sent by the client, but I don't know how to get the value which is already in the DB. Would it be possible to do this check with a validate method or should I try a different way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could access the existing `device_date` from `self.instance`:

```
def validate_device_date(self, value):

    if self.instance.pk:
        if value <= self.instance.device_date:
            raise ValidationError('Your custom exception message')

    return value
```

You do need to check if the instance exists before comparing so you don't raise an error while creating a new item.

Also note that this doesn't raise `HTTP 400` but a `ValidationError` which will be reported.